# Excel formula with a multiple formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I require a formula to count the number of times a word appears in a range and out of this range I need to count the number of blank spaces in another range with reference only to the first formula.

These are my two formulas that work separately however I need the total number together.
=COUNTIF(G2:G473,G476)
=COUNTBLANK(D2:D472)

So if the first formual is requal to 50 I want to know how many of those 50 from column G have a blank space in row D.

Comment: Use `COUNTIFS` instead of `COUNTIF`. Make sure the size of the two ranges is equal: in the example you give you have one range ending at row 472 and the other at row 473.

Comment: Thank you. Still no luck. What do I put between the two formulas so they are both considered? I've tried & and *
=COUNTIFS(G2:G470,G474)*COUNTBLANK(D2:D472)

Comment: You don't use 2 formulas. You use a single formula (COUNTIFS) which references both ranges with an appropriate criteria for each.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Table showing Things and One column of Spaces or No Space]

In the range A2:A30; I have entered few words.
In A33 = CAT, say. Look Up Value.
In B2 enter the formula ; A2=$A$33,   Just to check whether it is true or false for CAT
Copy this formula of B2; down the colomn. Wherever  CAT it will show TRUE.
In Column D; List of  words,  given or not given. That means Space or No Space.
In Cell C2 enter the formula;  =D2=””.  If Space TRUE else FALSE will be displayed.
Now in Cell  B33 enter the following formula ;
B33=    COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$30,A33,$B$2:$B$30,TRUE,$C$2:$C$30,TRUE)
For CAT it displays 9.
In place of CAT in A33; you can place DOG, APPLE, LION,  etc, to confirm the formula.
THANKS.

Answer (score 0):

try this in cell

```
B33 = COUNTIF($A$2:$A$30,A33)-COUNTIF(D2:D30,A33)
```